# Navigation arrow is not displayed on actionbar on left which acts as back - android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back-button

I am using actionbar in my application.
I add backbutton on actionbar. On its click back function is called.
But left arrow which is usually displayed on actionbar is not getting displayed.

I am trying with following code:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

If you're using the support library to support Android pre-3.0 use this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```